# How to ignore a group of elements if a specific node does not exist XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
<files>
<segmentpair>
<source>2. als Vertreter der xxxx ein Professor der Materialwissenschaft oder der Engineering Science und</source>
<target>2. as a representative of the University of xxxxx, a professor of materials science or engineering science</target>
<Comments>
<Comment>[xxx 09.01.2014 15:09:23] some comment on the translation</Comment>
</Comments>
</segmentpair>
</files>
</file>
```

into

```
<Feedback>[xxx 09.01.2014 15:09:23] some comment on the translation</Feedback>
<Source>2. als Vertreter der xxxx ein Professor der Materialwissenschaft oder der Engineering Science und</Source>
<Target>2. as a representative of the University of xxxxx, a professor of materials science or engineering science</Target>
```

I'm just not sure what to use to not display the target and source elements if no comments are present. For each and if? This code was just an idea to test whether the node exists but I don't think this is the right way and it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xml:output method="xml" version="1.0"  indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document>

            <xsl:for-each select="/files/file/segmentpair">
            <xsl:if test="Comments">
            <feedback>
                <xsl:value-of select="Comments/comment"/>
            </feedback>

         </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </document>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would be so grateful for help, I've read many examples here but I've got the point where I can't work out the most efficient way, I think I could be missing out on something simpler with XSLT 2.0.

Thanks
D.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If no comments are present, and you don't want to display the target and source elements in such case, then what should be the actual output? -- Note also that the output you do show is missing a root element, thus not a well formed XML.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, I intended document to be the root element and for only document to be shown if there was no comment, exactly how you answered. I learnt a lot from your answer, thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <xsl:for-each select="file/files/segmentpair[Comments/Comment]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Comments/Comment"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="source|target"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </document>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Comment">
    <feedback>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </feedback>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <feedback>[xxx 09.01.2014 15:09:23] some comment on the translation</feedback>
   <source>2. als Vertreter der xxxx ein Professor der Materialwissenschaft oder der Engineering Science und</source>
   <target>2. as a representative of the University of xxxxx, a professor of materials science or engineering science</target>
</document>
```

If no `Comment` element is present, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document/>
```

If multiple `Comment` elements are found, each will be output as a `feedback` element.

Note that XML is case-sensitive: `comment` is not the same thing as `Comment`.